# Why system assigns a "volume name" for a binded "/tmp"?

Tags: mount, bind, tmp

(The problem is found on: KUbuntu 13.10)

---

1. Initially */tmp* is not binded.
2. System has a volume with a label "Vol_2" (e.g., */dev/sda2)*.
3. A user logs in.
4. The user mounts the volume "Vol_2" to */media/Vol_2* (if this drive is not mounted yet; this one might be mounted in the previous session).
5. The user starts the file manager (Dolphin).
6. Device list contains an item "Vol_2". The file manager (Dolphin) for this device displays content of "*(/dev/sda2)/*".
7. The user runs:
   *sudo mount --bind /media/Vol_2/tmp /tmp*
8. The user starts the file manager (Dolphin).
9. Device list contains an item "Vol_2". The file manager (Dolphin) for this device displays content of "*(/dev/sda2)/**tmp***" (not "*(/dev/sda2)**/***").

**10. Why?** Is this behavior defined by Ubuntu or by KDE?

11. The file manager (Dolphin) displays proper content of the folder "*/media/Vol_2*".

Comment: I tried to do as described there 

(sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/Vol_2; sudo mount --bind /mnt/Vol_2/tmp /tmp).

It does not work (i.e., there are no any desired changes).

Answer (score 0):

**THE ANSWER IS (found by me):**

Probably (as I can see), if a volume has more than 1 mountpoint, software (like file managers) always get **FIRST** mountpoint and associate this one with the volume label.

Mountpoints are ordered (as I can see) **alphabetically, by descending**.

In the case described above, a solution may be: to mount the volume to a folder, which has path (as string) alphabetically > than "*/tmp*". Eg., the volume may be mount to "*/zmedia/Vol_2*".

---

I see that it works in my system.